# Has MapInfo text objects formatting tags as ArcMap annotations?

Tags: mapinfo, annotation, text, formatting

Esri ArcMap allows you to set annotation formatting via [formatting tags](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00s800000017000000.htm), eg:

```html
<FNT name="Arial" size="12">Text size = 12</FNT>
<FNT name="Arial" scale="200">Text scale = 200</FNT>
```

Through formatting tags we can set one part of annotation with one font style and a different font for other parts.

Does MapInfo have such functionality?
If yes, what is it called and what versions support it?

Answer (score 1):

A single Label in MapInfo Pro can only use one font.

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you could have the layer multiple times in the map and have different label settings for each layers, potentially showing the labels from the first layers with a red label at point size 12 and the labels from the second layer with a blue label at point size 14.

This would probably also require that you choose different positions for the two layers, for example the first layer top right and the second layer center right.

[image]